# How to keep position of these tagHovers close to tags while scrolling and the tagHover has fixed position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-position

**https://plnkr.co/edit/PuP3f71kCjkqgjjMkgNS?p=preview** | Also have a stackoverflow snippet below.

Without scrolling the tagHovers will display correctly:

#### The problem

I think the problem is because I have a `fixed` position set on the tagHovers `tags-modal` class. However I need the `fixed` position on that div so the tagHovers can break outside of the constraints of the `.tags-container`.

Is there another way to achieve this effect without having to restyle the tagHovers so they have to fit inside the tiny width size of the `tags-column`?

**Correct position without scrolling**
[image]

**Once you scroll, position of the fixed tagHover breaks**
[image]

However once I started scrolling, the tagHovers lose their relative position to the tag you hovered.

---

`.tags-container` which has an `overflow-y: auto;` To display scrolling.

Each tag has an associated `tag-hover` directive.

The tagHovers have this styling (So they can be displayed outside of the constraints of the tags-column.)

#### CSS

https://gist.github.com/leongaban/eb2988a1ff01ada78ea0f663fd0432a8

#### TagHover.html

```
<section class="tags-modal" ng-show="tghov.tag.hoverDisplay" ng-mouseleave="tghov.leave()">
    <h1>Hover for: {{ tghov.tag.term }}</h1>
</section>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.component('tagHover', {
//      templateUrl: 'tags_modal.html',
  template: `<section class="tags-modal" ng-show="tghov.tag.hoverDisplay" ng-mouseleave="tghov.leave()">
  <h1>Hover for: {{ tghov.tag.term }}</h1>
</section>`,
  controllerAs: 'tghov',
  bindings : {
      tag: '<'
  }
})
.controller('TagsHoverController', function(){});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {},
//  templateUrl: 'tags.html',
  template: `<section class="tags-view">
  <div class="tags-column">
    <h1>Tags</h1>
    <div class="tags-container">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tag in tgs.tags">
          
          <div class="tag-container-container" ng-mouseleave="tgs.leaveTag(tag)">
            <div class="tag-container">
              <div class="tag" ng-mouseover="tgs.tagHover(tag)">{{ tag.term }}</div>
              <tag-hover tag="tag"></tag-hover>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tags-content">
    <div class="tags-box">
      <h2>Tags Content</h2> 
    </div>
  </div>
</section>`,
  controllerAs: 'tgs',
  controller: TagsCtrl
});


TagsCtrl.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$uibModal'];

function TagsCtrl(
    $scope,
    $uibModal) {
    ///////////////////////////////////
    
    this.hello = "hello world";
    
    this.leaveTag = (tag) => tag.hoverDisplay = false;
    
    this.tagHover = (tag) => tag.hoverDisplay = true;
    
    this.tags = [
      { id:0, term: 'apple'},
      { id:1, term: 'butter'},
      { id:2, term: 'charlie'},
      { id:3, term: 'duff'},
      { id:4, term: 'edward'},
      { id:5, term: 'freddy'},
      { id:6, term: 'george'},
      { id:7, term: 'henry'},
      { id:8, term: 'ink'},
      { id:9, term: 'joker'},
      { id:10, term: 'kevin'},
      { id:11, term: 'leon'},
      { id:12, term: 'mary'},
      { id:13, term: 'nancy'},
      { id:14, term: 'olivia'},
      { id:15, term: 'preston'},
      { id:16, term: 'quincy'},
      { id:17, term: 'robyn'},
      { id:18, term: 'steven'},
      { id:19, term: 'teddy'},
      { id:17, term: 'ulysses'},
      { id:18, term: 'victor'},
      { id:19, term: 'winston'},
      { id:20, term: 'xavier'},
      { id:20, term: 'yvette'},
      { id:21, term: 'zander'}
    ];
}
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.tags-hover-container {
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    left: 240px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

.tags-column {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  max-width: 230px;
  min-width: 230px;
  height: calc(100% - 165px);
}

.tags-column li {
  list-style: none;
}

.tags-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 320px;
}

.tag-container-container { float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; }

.tag-container { float: left; position: relative; }

.tags-content {
  float: left;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.tags-box {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 640px;
  background: #4169E1;
}

.tags-box h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

.tag {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #3D3D3D;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;
}

.tag:hover {
  background: #656565;
}

.tags-modal {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  left: 100px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tags-modal:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 26px;
    z-index: 99;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0; width: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-component></my-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: move u code to the snippet

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Added the correct code snippet into my question post!

Comment: Yea, I tried tinkering with it for a bit, but came up with no resolution that allow the hover to display above the scrollbar. You may want to consider changing the markup, or using js to position the hover element.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying out the javascript route!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! Yeah there is no CSS solution to this, I had to figure out the current mouse y position and use ng-style to updated the styling on the fly.

#### TickersPanelComponent

```
this.hoverTicker = (event, ticker) => {
    MousePosition.set(event);
    const mouseY = MousePosition.current.y;
    ticker.pos = { top: `${mouseY}px` };
    ticker.hoverDisplay = true;
};
```

#### TickersPanel markup (contains tagHover component with ticker passed in)

```
<div class="tag-container" ng-mouseleave="tikp.leaveTicker(ticker)">
    <div class="ticker"
         ng-mouseenter="tikp.hoverTicker($event, ticker)"
         ng-click="tikp.selectTicker('portfolio', ticker);">
         <span ng-if="ticker.long && !ticker.hoverDisplay">
            {{ ticker.short }}
         </span>
         <span ng-if="!ticker.long || ticker.hoverDisplay">
            {{ ticker.ticker }}
         </span>
    </div>
    <ticker-hover ticker="ticker"></ticker-hover>
</div>
```

#### MousePosition Factory

```
const set = (e) => {
    current.x = e.pageX;
    current.y = e.pageY;
}
```

#### Finally tagHover markup

```
<div class="ticker-hover-container"
    ng-style="tkhov.ticker.pos" ng-show="tkhov.ticker.hoverDisplay">
```

^ `tkhov` is the `controllerAs` `this`